# How to install Openfire on windows 8.1 64-bit with external database

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire

I try to install openfire but I have some error, I don't understand why I cannot install successfully Openfire 3.9.3 . when I choose : **Standard Database Connection 
Use an external database with the built-in connection pool.**

=> I use `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ for mysql`

Database Driver Presets:**MySql**

JDBC Driver Class:**com.mysql.jdbc.Driver**

Database URL:`jdbc:mysql://[localhost]:3306/[dbopenfire]?rewriteBatchedStatements=true`

Username:**root**

//Left blank

Password:

what is the problem?

many thanks.

error.log:

```
    2014.07.27 20:57:33 org.jivesoftware.util.log.util.CommonsLogFactory - Prototype
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor13.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1127)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:356)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2502)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2539)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2321)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor10.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.DefaultConnectionBuilder.buildConnection(DefaultConnectionBuilder.java:39)
    at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.Prototyper.buildConnection(Prototyper.java:159)
    at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.Prototyper.sweep(Prototyper.java:102)
    at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.PrototyperThread.run(PrototyperThread.java:44)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: [localhost]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:250)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:306)
    ... 17 more
2014.07.27 20:58:03 org.jivesoftware.util.log.util.CommonsLogFactory - Prototype
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor13.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1127)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:356)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2502)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2539)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2321)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor10.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.DefaultConnectionBuilder.buildConnection(DefaultConnectionBuilder.java:39)
    at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.Prototyper.buildConnection(Prototyper.java:159)
    at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.Prototyper.sweep(Prototyper.java:102)
    at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.PrototyperThread.run(PrototyperThread.java:44)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: [localhost]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:250)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:306)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: You should change from: 
jdbc:mysql://[localhost]:3306/[dbopenfire]?rewriteBatchedStatements=true
to 
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbopenfire?rewriteBatchedStatements=true